# How to call one defn function in another defn and how to debugging in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am having a problem running my program in Clojure. I just start learning Clojure a couple of weeks ago. So I don't know the quick and easy way to debug a Clojure program. My func2 raises an exception at `(adj(a b))` as followed:

> ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn 
>   user/func2.

I don't know what is wrong with it. Can someone point out the problem with my coding? 
And in func3, I call `func2` recursively, but it throws:

> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector 
>   clojure.lan g.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)

What is wrong with func3? Thank you.

```
(defn adj [value1 value2]
    (def result (+ (/ value1 2) (/ value2 2)))  
    (if (= (mod result 2) 1)
        (+ result 1)
        result
    )
)

(defn func2 [list]
    (let [[a b c d] list] 
        (inc d)
        ([(adj c a) (adj a b) (adj b c) d]))    
)

(defn func3 [list]
    (loop [v list r []]

    (if(= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))
        (conj list r)               
        (func3(func2(list)))
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the intended result of these functions? We probably need to see some sample inputs and expected results to really be able to help you.

Here's my attempt at cleaning them up. I've noted the changes I made as comments. `func3` has the most serious problem in that it's an infinite recursion - there's no end condition. What should cause it to stop working and return a result?

```
(defn adj [value1 value2]
   ;; don't use def within functions, use let
  (let [result (+ (/ value1 2) (/ value2 2))]
    (if (= (mod result 2) 1)
      (+ result 1)
      result)))

(defn func2 [list]
  (let [[a b c d] list]
    ;; The extra parens around this vector were causing it
    ;; to be called as a function, which I don't think is
    ;; what you intended:
    [(adj c a) (adj a b) (adj b c) d]))

;; This needs an end condition - it's an infinite recursion
(defn func3 [list]
  (loop [v list r []]
    (if (= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))
      (conj list r)
      ;; Removed extra parens around list
      (func3 (func2 list)))))
```

The reason I say not to use `def` within functions is that it *always* creates a global function. For local bindings you want `let`.

Regarding the extra parens, the difference between `[1 2 3]` and `([1 2 3])` is that the former returns a vector containing the numbers 1, 2, and 3, whereas the latter tries to call that vector as a function. You had excess parens around the literal vector in `func2` and around `list` in `func3`, which was causing exceptions.

As a style note, the name `list` isn't a good choice. For one thing, it's shadowing `clojure.core/list`, and for another you're probably using vectors rather than lists anyway. It would be more idiomatic to use `coll` (for collection) or `s` (for sequence) as the name.

This would suggest at least one other change. In `func3` you use a vector-only feature (using the vector as a function to perform lookup by index), so to be more general (accept other data structures) you can convert to a vector with `vec`:

```
(defn func3 [coll]
  (loop [v (vec coll) r []]
    (if (= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))
      (conj v r)
      (func3 (func2 v)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanations and comments. I seem to like Clojure and hope to explore more into it. Can you suggest an easy way of debugging a Clojure program?

Comment: I'd recommend working at the REPL, starting with small pieces, and building up from there. You can evaluate individual expressions and then, once you know they work as intended, combine them into one or more functions. That way when something doesn't work you'll know exactly where the error was - in the expression you just tried to evaluate. This interactive style of development is pretty common among Lisps, including Clojure, and is very useful for learning and building your experience.

Comment: You may already know this, but the function `pst` might be helpful sometimes.  It prints a stacktrace of the last error.  It's a Java stacktrace, so it's not pretty, but sometimes there is useful information in the Java stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there is no need to debug that. I suggest you have a look at LightTable.

The first two functions are easily fixed:

```
(defn adj [value1 value2]
  ;(def result (+ (/ value1 2) (/ value2 2))) def creates a global binding in current namespace !!!  
  (let [result (+ (/ value1 2) (/ value2 2))]  
  (if 
    (= (mod result 2) 1)
    (inc result)
    result)))

(defn func2 [xx]
  (let [[a b c d] xx] 
    [ (adj c a) (adj a b) (adj b c) (inc d)]
    ))
```

The third function is not clear to me. I don't read your intent. What I understand is: "Keep applying func2 to itself until the first three elements of its result are equal." But I'm afraid this condition is never met, so I replaced it with a true in order to see just one result without blowing the stack.

```
(defn func3 [xx]
  (loop [ v (func2 xx) ]
    (if
      ;(= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))
      true
      v               
      (recur (func2 v))
    )))
```

Useful link: http://clojure.org/cheatsheet

Cheers -